# How to have crisp, sharp and slim jqueryUI GUI elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I like to have **thin** button sizes and bar sizes, but when i use jQueryUI, i get thick bars (title bar etc) and thick rounded buttons.

like this:

[image: default jQueryUI buttons an dbar sizes]

How can I have buttons and title/tab bars **thin, rectangular and crisp**?

like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Do you have some code which you have tried?

Have you tried reducing the amount of padding for those elements.

Comment: You're going to have to customize and possibly override the [jQuery UI theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) you are using to accomplish this.  A corner radius of 0px will remove the rounding, and a smaller font size will reduce the size some.

Comment: thx. on theme roller, i tried to reduce the font seize, but the buttons and tab still look so big. The 0px did change the corners to pointed. Wanting slim and sharp looking tabs/buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two basic options for creating a custom theme.

The first is to read the [documentation for the jQuery UI CSS framework](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/). There are only a handful of classes to learn about; the framework is very simplistic, but is designed in a way that these few classes will affect every single widget in jQuery UI.

The second option is to head over to the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and visually build a theme, then download it. This is just a GUI that will customize the classes from the CSS Framework linked above.

For things that affect dimensions, like padding and margin, you'll need to drop into the individual widget styling. You can see the classes for each widget in the API documentation. For example, here is the [theming information for tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#theming). For changes to individual widget classes, I'd recommend leaving the existing CSS alone and writing new rules to override the built-in settings. This will give you a clean upgrade path.

Comment: thx, when i change the font size for tab title, the font for content is also changed. how can i have diff fonts and sizes for title and content?  i tried: .ui-widget {
 font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: .9em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
 font-size: .75em;
}

Comment: Also, i too like to keep the orig code as-is, so i put my changes in seperate .css and got the desired results. reducing the font, changing border & padding to 0 and margin to 0 did it.